# HEAD HTTP Request doesnt return headers?

Tags: iis, iis-7, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

I am doing a simple HTTPRequest and it seems like when I perform a `HEAD` request instead of `GET` the Headers variable comes up blank, but not the other way around.

THIS RETURNS ALL HEADERS:

```
    objHTTPRequest.Open "GET", sURL, False
    objHTTPRequest.Send
        strHeaders = objHTTPRequest.getAllResponseHeaders()
        strResponseBody = objHTTPRequest.ResponseBody
```

THIS DOESN'T RETURN ANY HEADERS:

```
    objHTTPRequest.Open "HEAD", sURL, False
    objHTTPRequest.Send
        strHeaders = objHTTPRequest.getAllResponseHeaders()
        strResponseBody = objHTTPRequest.ResponseBody
```

NOTE: I get a status `200 OK` for both.

I am requesting a URL on my own server and have verified that the Handler Mapping allows ALL VERBS (Post,Get,Head..) for the file type, so I'm not sure why I'm not getting this data, anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is your handler for HEAD does not behave the same as one for GET/POST (assuming some sort of ASP.Net or other server side code handlers).

I believe the behavior is ok as there is no requirement that headers will be the same for all types of requests.

Comment: Is this something that can be configured on the server serving the HEAD/GET requests?

Comment: @ZeeTee - I don't know - you did not provide any information on what type of handler you expect to be hit with requests (physical file directly by IIS, some sort of ASP.Net/PHP/whatever handler, redirect,...) - so not possible to suggest the fix. (Note: it is unlikely I could suggest anything beyond ASP.Net config due to my limited knowledge of IIS)